# Uniqueness of holomorphic function satisfying differential equation

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I am asked to show that there exists at most one holomorphic function $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$, such that both
$$ f'(z) = \sin(z)f(z) + e^{z^2}$$
and $f(0) = 3+2i$ are satisfied. I have, to be honest, never really come across complex differential-equations and I am somewhat set off. I thought about restricting $f$ to the real axis to obtain a real-valued inital-value problem (that would then have uniqueness according to Picard-Linedeloef), but that seems odd since the initial value for $z=0$ has non-zero imaginary part.

I also tried to derive the power series for $f$, but that gets very messy...

Any hints?

Comment: When you restrict to the real axis, you get a(n inhomogeneous) linear ODE $y'(t) = A(t)y(t) + B(t)$ where $y \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: If $f$ is a solution, then $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_n z^n$ for all $z$.

Comment: Suppose there's two solutions $f_1, f_2$. Then their difference is constant everywhere. Since their initial value is the same, that constant must be $0$.

Comment: @George Immediately, the difference is just a solution to $g'(z)=\sin(z) g(z)$ with $g(0)=0$ (and in fact without $g(0)=0$, the solution would not be constant)

Comment: Maybe rthe problem is easier if you generalize: "Let $g,h$ be entire. Then there exists at most one entire $f$ with $f'=gf+h$."

Comment: Okay, so building on Hagen's idea: the difference $g=f_1-f_2$ for two solutions satifies $g'(z)= \sin(z)g(z)$ and $g(0)=0$. Since this ODE is Picard-Lindelöf, and 0 is an equilibrium, we must have $g(z) = 0$ on some open set $I$ with $0 \in I$. Hence, $g(z) = 0$ everywhere. (Technically, since the restriction is a map $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$, I would have to argue with the corresponding two-dimensional equation, which however does not essentially change the argument, right?)
Does that sound valid?

Comment: Or you could look at $h(z) = g(z)\cdot e^{\cos z}$ and compute $h'$.

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

We have the following theorems from real ODE's:

**1.** The Picard-Lindelöf theorem: If $(x,y)\mapsto f(x,y)$ is continuous in $\Omega\subset{\mathbb R}^2$ and locally Lipschitz with respect to $y$, and if $(x_0,y_0)\in\Omega$ then the IVP
$$y'=f(x,y),\quad y(x_0)=y_0$$
has a unique solution $x\mapsto y(x)$ defined in a neighborhood of $x_0$.

**2.** If $y'=p(x)y+q(x)$ is a linear ODE with $p(\cdot)$, $q(\cdot)$ continuous in an interval $-\infty\leq a<x<b\leq\infty$ then any solution can be uniquely extended to the full interval $\>]a,b[\>$.

The proofs of these theorems can be transferred verbatim to a complex environment, the result being that your IVP has a uniquely defined solution $z\mapsto f(z)$, which is an entire function of $z$.