# Flow of a vanishing Vector Field.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

Let us consider a complete vector field $V:\Bbb C^n\to\Bbb C^n$.

Let us call $\phi_s:\Bbb C^n\to\Bbb C^n$ its flow at time $s\in\Bbb C$, that is

$$
\dot{\phi}_s(x)=V(\phi_s(x))\;\;\forall x\in\Bbb C^n, s\in\Bbb C
$$
$$
\phi_0(x)=x\;\;\forall x\in\Bbb C^n
$$

How can I prove that $V\equiv0$ on $A$ implies $\phi_s(x)=x \;\;\forall x\in A$ and $s\in\Bbb C$?

Set $A$ as the common zero-set of a finite number of holomorphic polynomials (but maybe my statement holds for more general sets $A$, like closed sets).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that $V$ is Lipschitz continuous in $x$, so that we have [existence and uniqueness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) of solutions of

$\dot \phi_s(x) = V(\phi_x(x)), \tag 1$

then we need merely observe that

$\phi_s(x_0) = x_0 \tag 2$

satisfies

$\dot \phi_s(x_0) = 0 = V(\phi_s(x_0)), \; \forall x_0 \in A, \; s \in \Bbb C; \tag 3$

that is, constant function (2) obeys (1) on $A$; therefore, uniqueness implies it is the only such solution; $V = 0$ on $A$ implies (2) for all $s$.

Though the standard existence and uniqueness result cited and linked here is usually stated in terms of a real independent variable $s$, its extension to complex $s$ is straightforward; see [this question for further details](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2235415/uniqueness-of-holomorphic-function-satisfying-differential-equation).

Comment: A solution of (1) is a 1-parameter family of diffeomorphisms $\{\psi_s:\Bbb C^n\to\Bbb C^n\}_{s\in\Bbb C}$ such that $\psi_0=\operatorname{id}_{\Bbb C^n}$ and (1) is verified for all $x\in\Bbb C^n$ and all $s\in \Bbb C$. Now for every $x_0\in A$ you defined the constant maps $\Bbb C\ni s\mapsto\psi_s(x_0):=x_0$. Then, one observes that it satisfies (1) for all $s\in\Bbb C$ and $x\in A$. But, this is not a solution of (1) because we miss to define the maps on $\Bbb C^n\setminus A$, so it has no sense to talk about uniqueness of "solution". Isn't it?

Comment: @Joe:  I'm going to need a little time to digest your remarks.  Will try and get back to you soon.

Comment: Thank you very much Robert. I will think about it too!

Answer (score 1):

If $V_x=0$ for some $x\in\mathbb{C}^n$, then the curve $\gamma:s\mapsto x$ is solution of $\dot\gamma(s)=V_{\gamma(s)}$ (since both sides are $0$) and $\gamma(0)=x$. Since two integral curves who coincides at a point are the same, you can conclude that $\varphi_s(x)=\gamma(s)=x$ for all $s\in\mathbb{R}$. Since it is correct for all such $x\in\mathbb{C}^n$, you get what you want.